# how to find files in the company's SVN server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In our company, we use SVN server to save some documents. We use TortoiseSVN to access a URL, such as“ https://200.200.0.1/svn/... ”, then log in with my account & password, and finally view the documents. But TortoiseSVN does not support searching for files.

I hope there is a software to solve this problem, whether it is Linux or windows

thank you

Comment: Current VisualSVN Server version supports finding files by name in the web interface in the web interface. This feature was introduced in [VisualSVN Server 4.2](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/4.2/) and you can try it on the [demo server](https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/view/head/subversion).

Comment: If you had command-line svn you could run `svn ls --recursive <url>` and save the output to a text file that you could search through to find things. But I don't know if Tortoise lets you do that.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a file search feature in the svn version 1.14.

For your scenario you need to put in the command:

`svn list --recursive --search "search_term" <url>`

Or you can use some viewers like [websvn](https://websvnphp.github.io) and [visualsvnserver](http://www.visualsvn.com/) to do the same.